# Как назначить текущий таб в QTabWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtabwidget

Создал несколько tabWidget, одну из них - вкладка "Главная".

Как сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы она всегда открывалась первой, а не остальные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Андрей, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и объясните лучше, что у вас при каждом запуске происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Надо в конструкторе окна, в котором находится `QTabWidget` программно указать какой именно таб является текущим ([док](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTabWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget.setCurrentWidget)):

```
class Window(...):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.tabMain)
```

Здесь `tabMain` это ваш виджет "Главная". При этом, как сказано в документации:

> Виджет должен быть страницей в этом таб-виджете

Второй способ. В дизайнере формы `QtDesigner` - последний, или текущий  выбранный/открытый таб будет первым при запуске программы